# Appium: Github username needed when running bootstrap script

Tags: appium

I have installed `1.6.0_beta3` since my company's app depends on `Xcode 8`.

When running the bootstrap script as explained I need to enter my github username. 
Why? It's a public repository. Nothing happens when I enter my github username.

```
XXX:WebDriverAgent YYY$ ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh
Fetching dependencies
Username for 'https://github.com': (displayed 3 times)
```

I also tried with:

```
./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -D
```

Comment: Issue is still visible with Appium 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like more things were broken after updating OSX. Thanks Appium.

1. $ cd /usr/local
2. $ git reset --hard
3. $ git clean -df
4. $ brew update
5. $ brew upgrade carthage